# alphabetically sort array based on first few strings

Tags: php, arrays, string

I woud like to sort an array which typically includes names and email addresses. The problem is that the email addresses appear last even though they may start with 'a'

e.g.

```
$myarray = ("Alex Mayfeild", "David Beckham", "Oliver Twist", "ant.stev@wherever.com", "peter.pan@neverland.com", ........) //and so on
```

Upon sorting the array using php's sort function "ant.stev@wherever.com" will appear close to the end even though the functionality I would like to achieve is for him to appear after Alex.

natcasesort and natsource functions based on natural ordering seem to fail. **Correction: natcasesource works it returns true when working as stated in docs. Thanks @meagar**

Is there anyway to achieve the requested functionality. Thanks for any help guys. It is very much appreciated.

Comment: @KalpeshMehta isn't that mostly for associative arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort()` is case sensitive, as it sorts based on the letters ASCII value.

Try [`natcasesort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php), if you want too "sort an array using a case insensitive 'natural order' algorithm".

Comment: Does case sensitive natural order take into account the `@` and `.`s?

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me that [`sort($myarray, SORT_STRING|SORT_FLAG_CASE);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) should sort the array the way you want.